# I'm trying to figure out how to return circumference of all circles drawn

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to return total circle sizes using recursive function, error: "float object is not callable"

```
def draw(n, r):
    if n == 0:
       pass
    else:
       turtle.circle(r)
       return 2 * math.pi() * r + draw(n-1, r+1)
```

Comment: Math.pi is a float. So remove the parenthesises

Comment: Also, once you fix that, you will get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'` error. Replace `pass` with `return 0.`

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning @Sem Redways comment to an answer

You must distinguish between  functions and members of a class or a module. 
Functions / Methods will get called with brackets, while variables are just simply called. The code has to be changed to:

```
def draw(n, r):
    if n == 0:
       return 0
    else:
       turtle.circle(r)
       return 2 * math.pi * r + draw(n-1, r+1)
```